# Qt font renders weird on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I just started using Qt (using Qt 5 beta 1), and I found that the fonts rendered in OS X 10.6.8 are messed up. I've tried using different fonts, but they all look like the image I've posted below (very thin, pixelated). How can I get the fonts to render correctly?

The code I'm using is simply:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel label("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog...");
    label.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5lqg.png]

Comment: Change font smoothing setting in System Preferences -> Appereance.

Comment: From your code, this should render like any other simple dialog on your platform. I am wary about the Qt version you are using, though. Do you get the same result with Qt 4?

Comment: @elmigranto Interesting... There was a dash in the checkbox for "Use LCD font smoothing when available." I disabled and reenabled it and it looks fine now! Thanks.