# Qt Quick Font Rendering Distortion when run inside Qt Creator

Tags: qt, fonts, qt-creator, qml, qt-quick

I am running this code inside Qt Creator 3.0.1 with Qt 5.2.1 (fresh install).
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-tutorial2.html

I get an error with font rendering similar to this issue:
[Qt font renders weird on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939540/qt-font-renders-weird-on-os-x)

But it looks even worse:
[image]

How can I get normal, "noiseless", font as expected for the outcome of this tutorial?

I am running this on Windows 7 64 bit. Intel Celeron CPU 900 @ 2.2 GHz 2.19 GHz.
Display adapter is Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family

Comment: Have you tried using import QtQuick 2.0 instead of import QtQuick 1.0?  Could be that the font rendering in the older QtQuick version is not so well supported. QtQuick 2.0 is the default for Qt5. You'll find the Qt5 version of the tutorial here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-tutorial2.html

Comment: I corrected my link. I actually was using qtquick 2.0 so +1 for the reminder and updated link.

Comment: It is imperative that you post the details of the machine you run it on: the exact OS X version, the hardware platform (like MacBookPro5,1 etc.), and the graphics hardware *presently active* (since you may have an active and an inactive adapter on mobile systems). This is likely a hardware-specific bug, since I haven't run into it yet, although all of my Intel Mac hardware is vintage at this point.